# בין אדם לחבירו - between man and his fellow man

Tags: words, women, bein-adam-lachavero

The translation of בין אדם לחבירו is *between man and his fellow man*.

1) Does בין אדם לחבירו also apply to women?

2) If it does, then shouldn't it be worded בין אשה לחבירה or בין אשה לחברתה?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just converting it to an answer, with the added Chikuni.

Hebrew is a gendered language, and uses the masculine as the default.

Here's is [Chizkuni's commentary to Genesis 1:27](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39852&pgnum=6):

[image: Image text of Chizkuni to Gensis 1:27]

> **We shall fashion an Adam** ... *human* in old French, i.e. "let us make a man and a woman." The proof text is later: "God called them *adam* the day they were created." We also find [Talmudically]: said Rav Huna, how do we know that Eve is also called *adam*? ... also, *and living* adam: *from the women* ...

Comment: That might work for אדם. What about חבירו? Last time I checked, חבירו means _his friend_, not _her friend_ which would be חברתה.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I think you have not understood the Shalom and msh210's answers. אדם is used in a masculine-by-default sense here. That's why we use חבירו.

Comment: @Daniel: Then tell me how you would accurately translate בין אדם לחבירו?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Between man and his fellow. The "man" is masculine-by-default as is the fellow. English doesn't have gender-neutral pronouns either, so the translation also uses masculine-by-default.

Comment: @Daniel: According to Shalom the translation of בין אדם לחבירו would be, _"Between one human and another."_

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah That is accurate.

Comment: Just as the Torah says to connect the Mishkan tapestries (which are conjugated in the feminine) *isha el achota*, "one to another." Not "each tapestry to her sister."

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. Because then the possessive pronoun ־ה (which is feminine) and its antecedent אדם (which is masculine) wouldn't [agree](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_agreement) in gender. (Word [gender](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender). Not sex of the referent.) That would break a standard rule of Hebrew grammar.

Perhaps you meant to propose instead that it should be בין אשה לחבירה. But then it would exclude men, by the long tradition in Hebrew of referring to people generally as אדם but never men as אשה.

Comment: Hebrew is a gendered language, and uses the masculine as the default. I should point out that when Genesis says "G-d created the *Adam* in the likeness of G-d, in male and female"; Chizkuni translates *Adam* as "human", gender-neutral for the species.

Comment: @Shalom: Can you send me a link to the Chizkuni?